# OUTLOOK 2013 on Win8 Email WAR

Tags: windows-8, email, microsoft-outlook

New Dell 8700 PC
Win 8 64bit OS
Outlook 2013

Want: 
IMAP Outlook email from my GMAIL acct.
Work email (Office 365) Exchange Server Acct in Outlook.

Problem:
I added both. Both work, but Work email will took over as "default data file" and my personal contacts.

I want the functionality of .OST (I think?) in which it has all the options for connecting social media accounts and updating contacts.

I want my contacts to be accessible from my Windows Acct contacts for my Windows 8 Phone, and Windows 8 Personal Laptop.

Is there a step by step guide to adding and home and work accounts in the best configuration for multiple device access?

Comment: Outlook as the ability to set the default data file have you tried to changed it?  .OST files are just cache files they cannot be migrated and backups cannot be made.  In order to sync your Google Contacts and your Office 365 contacts that requires an addon.

Comment: Please share the addon name or link/location if that is the answer to my question.

Comment: I did try to change it from my work file (dont necesarily want my personal contact stored on work server) It says it can't unless I disable cache mode, or switch to .pst.  Isn't .ost supposed to give me better synch/accesibility across multiple devices?

Comment: Again .OST is just a cache of the current state on the server.  An Exchange server will take priority over an IMAP/POP3 email account thats just how Outlook is designed.

Comment: there are dozens of possible addons the specific one you choose is up to you.

Comment: Does that mean that my personal contacts and email will now be stored on my employers server since it takes over as teh default data file?  If I have both accounts added in outlook it requires the Exchange Server be the default data file (Employer Email Acct) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your gmail contacts through IMAP, that's not going to happen. Right now, IMAP is an ***email only protocol***.